# Error (timeout?) when loading data into Vora 1.4

Tags: vora

I'm trying to create a Vora table and append data from an ORC file. So far hit a couple issues.

1. Appending data using the GUI (Vora Tools - Modeler - Append) seems to ignore "ORC" setting made in the dialog. This looks like a bug.
2. When trying to append multiple ORC files with the total of 29Mio records, the following message is presented:

   sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (could not handle api call, failure reason : execution of scheduler plan failed: internal error message: ttl exceeded, no response received: ttl=2m0s, task=1, nodes=[120];caught exception during execution of abort plan : Generic runtime error.(tx_id:31)) with error code 0, status ERROR_STATUS

It doesn't matter what engine I use, relational or disk, the message appears anyway. Is there some timeout setting to configure?

UPDATE: extra details on the issue #2.
Tx Coordinator log has got the following:

```
2017-09-18 09:54:17.088741|+1000|ERROR|error at processing of api call|tc103|Hana V2 API|140657103492864|ProcessRequest|v2net_request_handler.cpp(73)
...
2017-09-18 09:57:37.817268|+1000|ERROR|execution of scheduler plan failed: internal error message: ttl exceeded, no response received: ttl=2m0s, task=1, nodes=[121];|tc103|Hana V2 API|140657103492864|ExecutePhysicalPlan|tc_executor.cpp(1287)^^
2017-09-18 09:57:37.825402|+1000|ERROR|Could not found any service with the requested type.|tc103|Consul Client|140657103492864|CheckJSON|client_impl.cpp(398)^^
2017-09-18 09:57:37.827538|+1000|ERROR|Unable to dial node 121 using cached addr XXXXX:30507 - dial tcp XXXXX:30507: getsockopt: connection refused {node=103}|v2node|v2node|42|dial|node.go(495)^^
2017-09-18 09:58:08.084641|+1000|ERROR|error at processing of api call|tc103|Hana V2 API|140657103492864|ProcessRequest|v2net_request_handler.cpp(73)
```

Vora-manager

```
Sep 18 09:26:30 YYYYY consul[24535]: agent: Check 'service.vora-engine.YYYYY.115' missed TTL, is now critical
Sep 18 09:35:30 YYYYY consul[24535]: snapshot: Found temporary snapshot: 23-915905-1504365419402.tmp
Sep 18 09:35:30 YYYYY consul[24535]: snapshot: Found temporary snapshot: 64-915931-1504365663452.tmp
Sep 18 09:35:30 YYYYY consul[24535]: snapshot: Found temporary snapshot: 64-915931-1504365738659.tmp
Sep 18 09:53:46 YYYYY consul[24535]: agent: Check 'service.vora-engine.YYYYY.123' missed TTL, is now critical
Sep 18 09:55:54 YYYYY consul[24535]: memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: read tcp YYYYY:42137->XXXXX:8301: i/o timeout
Sep 18 09:56:00 YYYYY consul[24535]: memberlist: failed to receive: read tcp YYYYY:8301->XXXXX:50044: i/o timeout from=XXXXX:50044
Sep 18 09:56:00 eba156 consul[24535]: memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: read tcp YYYYY:42839->XXXXX:8301: i/o timeout
Sep 18 09:56:03 YYYYY consul[24535]: memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: read tcp YYYYY:43179->XXXXX:8301: i/o timeout
...
```

What's interesting, is that host XXXXX has only Vora computing services enabled, no control services.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. (1) Is there any more information in the logs of transaction coordinator logs or relational engine? (2) Was any of the Vora services restarted or did it crash? (3) Is there sufficient memory available to load the data? (i.e. how large is the ORC file size and how much free memory exists before the load). (4) Which Vora 1.4 version is this? Latest is Vora 1.4 patch 3 (1.4.0.33) - upgrading might be worth a try. There were some improvements e.g. if many ORC files are loaded. (5) Is the table partitioned? If not then the complete data will end up in one engine.

Comment: @FrankLegler 1) Added log details to the original post. 2) no components got restarted or crashed, 3) I can't swear on that, should be enough, judging by servers specs, but then the error happens when I use disk engine, too; 4) It's 1.4.0.27, which I I guess Patch 2. I noticed a newer version has been released on the 15th; will try installing it (wish I didn't have to do a complete reinstall every time); 5) the table is not partitioned, because for some reason my Vora Tools SQL Editor didn't allow me to use PARTITIONED BY statement (why would it?).